# BeautifulSoup is not showing all the meta keywords.. only partial keywords are there

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to extract all meta keywords from youtube page. But BuatifulSoup is only able to extract first few keywords instead of all. I wrote the following Python script to do this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

keywords = soup.find("meta", {"name": "keywords"})['content']
print(keywords)
```

And I am getting the following output:

```
Rewind, Rewind 2019, youtube rewind 2019, #YouTubeRewind, MrBeast, PewDiePie, James Charles, Shane Dawson, CaseyNeistat, RiceGum, Simone Giertz, JennaMarbles...
```

It is unable to extract all keywords. As if I go to the youtube page source, i am seeing the following thing:

[image]

Is there any way to capture the whole keyword lists? Or this is the BeautifulSoup restriction? If this is the restriction..... if there is any alternate solution to capture the tags?

Comment: Additional keywords you are searching are not in the `meta` tag, but in a `script` tag. You have actually already all the keywords inside the meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did was open response.text into pprint so I could get a clearer visualization. From there I searched for "Lilly" and found two places that the keywords could be extracted from. Obviously I chose the lower hanging fruit. But you definitely could go the route you were asking for, it would just take more work for what appears to be the same outcome. IMHO

Anyways, below is the code snippet that should solve your problem. You almost had it, you just needed to use "attrs" and extract from a different portion of the response. I hope you weren't too discouraged. Best of luck!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pprint as pp

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo"

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

for meta in soup.find_all(attrs={"property":"og:video:tag"}):
    print(meta["content"])
```

Response:

```
Rewind
Rewind 2019
youtube rewind 2019
#YouTubeRewind
MrBeast
PewDiePie
James Charles
Shane Dawson
CaseyNeistat
RiceGum
Simone Giertz
JennaMarbles
Lilly Singh
emma chamberlain
The Try Guys
Fortnite
Minecraft
Roblox
Marshmello
Garena Free Fire
GTA V
Lachlan
Anaysa
jeffreestar
Noah Schnapp
Jennelle Eliana
T-Series
Azzyland
LazarBeam
Dude Perfect
David Dobrik
KSI
NikkieTutorials
Kurzgesagt
Jelly
Ariana Grande
Billie Eilish
BLACKPINK
Year in Review
```

Comment: From your post, I learned something that its always a good idea to check the response data before starting parsing. It's really a great debugging technique which I missed. Now, I learned this tactics.

Comment: No, thank you. This gave me an idea to extract more data from YouTube. So I plan on bookmarking this for later use. But I'm happy I was able to help.